# div cannot be moved to the top

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

For some reason I can't position the last div with class `feature` to the top of the parent div.
First I tried it without the extra style-rule for the last `feature`-div, but no change. Now I tried it with the extra.

```
.feature:last-of-type {
    top: 0;
}
```

But just like before nothing happens. Slowly I'm really desperate where the mistake is..
I would be very grateful if someone could help me!

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="features">

  <div class="feature">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="img/30_Min_Recipes.png" alt="Täglich neue Rezepte">
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h3>30-Minuten-Rezepte</h3>
      <p>Entdecke täglich 3 neue Rezeptideen</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="img/Shopping.png" alt="Zutaten, die es in jedem Supermarkt gibt">
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h3>Einkaufsliste</h3>
      <p>Finde alle Zutaten in deinem Supermarkt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="img/Cooking.png" alt="Einfaches und gesundes Kochen">
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h3>Kochanleitung</h3>
      <p>Koche einfach & gesund</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

..and this my CSS:

```
/* ---Beginn--- Features */
#features {
    min-height: calc(85% - 108px*2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 108px 384px;

    background-color: var(--c-light-beige);
}

.feature {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 340px;
}

.feature:last-of-type {
    top: 0;
}

.feature .img-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 20px*2);
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.feature .text-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 40px*2);
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.feature img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.feature h3 {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--c-dark-beige);
}

.feature p {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--c-headline-dark);
}

/* ---Ende--- Features*/
```

Comment: I don't understand. You want the last `.feature` element to lay on top of the first one, or you want to change the order of them? Please revise your question to make it more clear what outcome you're after. A diagram would be great.

Comment: [Here's a playground](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2knm1rt6/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but your problem now is your last feature that's now at the top covers the original top item because it's out of the document flow.

Preferred fix for this is either make it correct in the HTML or use JavaScript to move that last container to the top in the DOM.

```css
/* ---Beginn--- Features */
#features {
    min-height: calc(85% - 108px*2);
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 108px 384px;

    background-color: var(--c-light-beige);
}

.feature {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 340px;
}

.feature:last-of-type {
/*I added this code */
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: violet;
    width: 100%;
    /* end added code */
}

.feature .img-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 20px*2);
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.feature .text-wrapper {
    width: calc(100% - 40px*2);
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.feature img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

.feature h3 {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--c-dark-beige);
}

.feature p {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: var(--c-headline-dark);
}

/* ---Ende--- Features*/
```

```html
<div id="features">

  <div class="feature">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="img/30_Min_Recipes.png" alt="Täglich neue Rezepte">
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h3>30-Minuten-Rezepte</h3>
      <p>Entdecke täglich 3 neue Rezeptideen</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="img/Shopping.png" alt="Zutaten, die es in jedem Supermarkt gibt">
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h3>Einkaufsliste</h3>
      <p>Finde alle Zutaten in deinem Supermarkt</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="feature">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img src="img/Cooking.png" alt="Einfaches und gesundes Kochen">
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h3>Kochanleitung</h3>
      <p>Koche einfach & gesund</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: First of all:Thanks for your answer. But the last feature shouldn't differ from the original document flow. It should be relatively next to the 2nd feature (in the middle) and this in turn next to the 1st feature (left).

Comment: But the upper edge of all 3 features should be at the same height. This works with my code for the first 2 features but not for the last one. I am wondering why `top: 0;` property isnt taking effect in my case. This is my problem :)

Comment: It's not making sense what you want, do you want columns or something else?

Comment: Sorry for being so stupid with saying what I want.. I want to rebuild this website to learn more about positioning, CSS and js:  https://www.kptncook.com/ And there I want to rebuild now the three "features" layout.

Comment: I see. If you want a 12 column layout to do three columns, there are many ways to do it. 1. Use a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation or 2. For three columns use 33.33% divs floated left and box-sizing: border-box so margin between them does not push the third one to the next line.

Comment: I tried your 2nd method described by you and it works! Thank you so much for your help! Now I'm one step further!